# Need Astroquery 4.1 installed visual studio

Tags: python, anaconda, astroquery

Visual studio
Python
Anaconda

Astroquery is supposed to be part of astropy.  Not there

Ive downloaded zip files and run them....nothing yet.  How to do it

Comment: please improve the question by adding code so we can understand the question.  use the ` characters before and after code blocks. 

probably worth going over the install/intro sections.
https://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#introduction

Comment: (1) Describe where and how you are stuck with the various sets of isntructions available on line.  (2) Post to an appropriate group, such as `SuperUser.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `conda install -c astropy astroquery` in your active conda evironment